# How to force SSL Wordpress on Google App Engine

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, google-app-engine, ssl

#### Steps Taken So far

From https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/securing-custom-domains-with-ssl

1. I have a custom domain.
2. i have verified a managed certificate has been provisioned
3. I have upgraded to managed SSL certificates automatically. Thanks Google
4. I have created a htaccess that Forces SSL

My Problem

1. After running `gcloud app deploy` my site goes to http instead of **https**.

See screenshot below 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

How's your site_url constant defined in your wp-config.php?

You probably also need to install a Force SSL or Simple SSL plugin. And define corresponding constants in your wp-config.php.

Comment: Dump the constants so you can see if it's actually set to https

Comment: How do I dump the constants?

Comment: var_dump($var). or if you enabled error log, you can do error_log(print_r($var, 1));

Comment: In My `wp-config.php` file I have added define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true); but no errors showing. Am I doing it the right way?

Comment: You need to set WP_DEBUG to true first. Also you can just use var_dump to dump your constant on your live app. It's easier. The point is to see if the constants are actually https.

Comment: Looks like I have to edit the 'nginx-app'.config page and not it works perfectly

Comment: I am running into this issue now. How did you configure the nginx-app.config file?

Answer (score 0):

The first option is to configure your website to work via HTTPS instead of HTTP. By default, WordPress is redirecting all of other links to the default protocol(in your case HTTPS).

You can configure it via WP-Cli. The command you need is:

```
wp search-replace 'OLD-URL' 'NEW-URL' --precise --recurse-objects --all-tables-with-prefix
```

You may check the following tutorial for more information: https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/

Another option is to set the 301 redirects in the .htaccess. I am using the following code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Additional information on these types of moves from Google can be found at: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6033049?hl=en&ref_topic=6033084

Comment: Did you replace the HTTP URLs in the database as per option one in my reply? You can try to use a plugin for search-replace in the database so all of the URLs are with HTTPS.

Comment: I did, however, with Google App Engine, I am using localhost:8080 to start the server. How do I change that so that I can use https on localhost and still be able to open the app on GAE?